# c++ oop errors. no matching function

Tags: c++, oop

i keep getting these errors when i compile

> 60 35 H:\OCC\student simulator program 2.cpp [Error] no matching
>   function for call to 'student::student(int, double, int, const char
>   [6])'
>
> 60 35 H:\OCC\student simulator program 2.cpp [Error] candidates are:
>
> 22 2 H:\OCC\student simulator program 2.cpp student::student()  22 2
>   H:\OCC\student simulator program 2.cpp   candidate expects 0
>   arguments, 4        provided
>
> 13 7 H:\OCC\student simulator program 2.cpp student::student(const
>   student&)  13 7 H:\OCC\student simulator program 2.cpp   candidate
>   expects 1 argument, 4 provided

code:

```
//student simulator

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class student {
private:
int     num;    //student num
float   grade;  //student grade
int     workEthic; //rating of student work ethic (1-10)
string personalityType; //string value 

public:

student() :num(0),grade(0),workEthic(0),personalityType("dead")
{}
void  askQuestion ()
{
    workEthic++;
    grade+=0.5;
}
void  sleep()
{
    workEthic=0;
    personalityType= "sleepy";
    grade-=3.3;

}
void  wake ()
{
    workEthic+=3;
    personalityType="awake";
    grade+=3.2;
}
void display()
{
    cout<<"id num="<<num<<endl;
    cout<<"grade="<<grade<<endl;
    cout<<"work ethic="<<workEthic<<endl;
    cout<<personalityType<<endl;
}
};


int main()
{
student matthew (5,96.5,2,"bored");
matthew.sleep();
matthew.display();
system("PAUSE");    

matthew.wake();
matthew.askQuestion();
matthew.display();
return 0;
}
```

im pretty new to c++ and i cant seem to figure out why this wrong.

Comment: One important thing to embrace when learning C++ is to use `std::string` instead of C-style strings and buffers. There's no reason why your string should only be able to handle five characters.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the error message:

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'student'

You didn't define a constructor that takes `int`, `float`, `int`, string literal.

Answer (score 1):

In `main()`, you call a constructor for `class student` that receives four arguments:

```
student matthew(5, 96.5, 2, "bored");
```

But your class only defines the default constructor that doesn't receive any arguments and initializes the class members with the values in parantheses:

```
student() :num(0), grade(0), workEthic(0), personalityType("dead")
    {}
```

You would call that default constructor in `main()` without arguments and without parantheses:

```
student matthew;
```

To supply initial values as you did inside `main()` with `student matthew(5, 96.5, 2, "bored");`, you have to add an overloaded constructor to `class student` that takes the four arguments and initializes the class members with the supplied values like:

```
student(int n, float g, int wE, string pT)
        : num(n),
          grade(g),
          workEthic(wE),
          personalityType(pT)
{}
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/V5nkAP)

Answer (score 0):

The class does not declare a constructor with four parameters. So this statement

```
student matthew (5,96.5,2,"bored");
```

is invalid.

You need to define in the class such a constructor to make the statement above correct.

At present the class has the default constructor that does not accept arguments.